# Is there a classic version of Eclipse Mars (4.5)

Tags: eclipse

The classic (stripped down versions) of [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) are notoriously hard to find on the eclipse website.

Does anybody know if there is a classic version of Eclipse Mars 4.5? What is its download link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you mean, but you should try this click path:

```
Eclipse-Homepage -> Downloads -> Other builds -> 4.5
```

Or this direct link: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5-201506032000/

There you will find the [*Eclipse SDK*](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5-201506032000/details.html#EclipseSDK), which AFAIK is what was also known as "Eclipse Classic" in earlier builds, and the [*Platform Runtime Binary*](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5-201506032000/details.html#PlatformRuntime), which is the "stripped down" Eclipse with no other plugins pre-installed.